# How to solve deployment error on glassfish server?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish-3

Hey I am getting following error while try to deploy my project on remote glassfish server using netbeans:

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE: Invalid resource : proximity__pm
```

But If I deploy this project on my local machine glassfish server it works fine.
I dont know why it gives me error on remote machine.
Please can any one help me and let me know what is the wrong in it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error can occur if your resources (connection pool, jdbc resource) are not deployed together with your application.

If you deploy with Netbeans locally, the IDE manages the deployment of resources for you. On a remote server if you only deploy the WAR file, resources will not be deployed automatically (unless you use application scoped resources).

You could either:

- try to set up your resources manually on the remote server *before*
  you deploy your app
- or change your application setting to use application scoped
  resources (which are then only available to the application they are
  deployed with and not to other web apps on the same server).

The documentation on application scoped GF resources is not very good at the moment. Best tutorial I found for my own project was this [video tutorial](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE0QtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlFRbN2Yb3g&ei=ijkSUKO3B82LswaUj4GIAg&usg=AFQjCNHv_uqmRm146HhsRBe122WT2xv2tw&sig2=U9DOx0vY9iXCGvY37_LNJw).

Comment: So, just define your jdbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the remote glassfish server logs and find out what the exact error message is.